# ReactJS: Return value when item is clicked (multi step form)

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to ReactJS. For a small project I am building, I have created a component which returns a value when a card item is clicked. The goal is to build a multi step form.

So far it works as expected but I am pretty sure I am not following best practices.

Especially the 3 event listeners seems to be to repetitive.

Does someone more experienced has suggestions on how to improve the code? Many thanks for your support. :)

```
  import React from 'react';
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
  import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
  import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

  // Styles for grid items/cards
  const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    paper: {
      height: 250,
      width: 200,
      margin: 20,
    },
  });

  // COMPONENT
  export class Form1 extends React.Component {
    state = {
      spacing: '0',
      step: 1,
      optionStep1: ''
    };

  // METHODS  
  // Proceed to next step
  nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState( {
      step: step + 1
    });
  }

  // Previus step
  prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState( {
      step: step - 1
    });
  }

  // Change Option of Step 1
  constructor(props) {    
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      optionStep1: ''
    };

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick1 = this.handleClick1.bind(this);
    this.handleClick2 = this.handleClick2.bind(this);
    this.handleClick3 = this.handleClick3.bind(this);
  }

  // Eventlisteners
  handleClick1() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      optionStep1: 'option 1 picked'
    })
    );
    console.log('option 1 picked');
  }

  handleClick2() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      optionStep1: 'option 2 picked'
    })
    );
    console.log('option 2 picked');
  }

  handleClick3() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      optionStep1: 'option 3 picked'
    })
    );
    console.log('option 3 picked');
  }

  // RENDER
    render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;
      const { spacing } = this.state;

      return (
        <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={16}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Grid container className={classes.demo} justify="center" spacing={Number(spacing)}>
                <Grid onClick={this.handleClick1}>
                  <Paper className={classes.paper} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid onClick={this.handleClick2}>
                  <Paper className={classes.paper} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid onClick={this.handleClick3}>
                  <Paper className={classes.paper} />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
  }

  Form1.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  export default withStyles(styles)(Form1);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is requesting a review of working code. It may be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting your component twice, you must have gotten an error about this somewhere. You can just write it like this using ES6 arrow functions:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form1 extends Component {
   state = {
      spacing: '0',
      step: 1,
      optionStep1: ''
   };


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SurveyForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form1;
```

You are making use of the Babel plugin that comes with `create-react-app` to initialize state, but then down a few lines you go and write out the `constructor()` in the classical way, initializing state twice.

After you initialize state, if you are changing that state you need to use `this.setState()`. I would also recommend using `redux-form` library.

Answer (score 0):

I would create only one `handleClick` function that would take an argument:

```
handleClick(option) {
  this.setState({
    optionStep1: `option ${option} picked`,
  });

  console.log(`option ${option} picked`);
}
```

And then you can call this generic function for each of your option elements:

```
<Grid onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}>
  <Paper className={classes.paper} />
</Grid>
```